# Access vba select new raw in datasheet view

Tags: vba, ms-access, select, datasheet, newrow

I have a datasheet view form. I want to add in it but when i set focus cause of sorting it select the top record which has data in it and edit it.
Question is how I can select the new row which has * beside it, so when I set focus it will create a new record.

HOW TO SELECT THE NEW RAW OF A DATASHEET VIEW FORM WITH VBA CODE?

Comment: Use a proper form with AcFormOpenDataMode set to acFormAdd see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx

Comment: hey just I want to select the new row which has star at the side.

Comment: Hey it's an emergency please HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert your new record with something like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL("insert into table1 (field1, field2)
    values( " & value1 & ", " & value2 & ")"
```

(or use parameters, that would be better), then do the `SetFocus` on your datatsheet.

Comment: Tnx Friend. That's true.

Answer (score 0):

Morteza,

By '*' I assume you mean the 'new record' symbol in the record selector box for a new record. If so, let me suggest something simple, and see if it works.

Put this code in the appropriate form or control event handler:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acNewRec
```

This should work in any form that has `Allow Additions` set to Yes.

Comment: Tnx Friend
I want to go to last row of current datasheet if I make a new record so it doesn't have the ID of current selection of table, but if go to current new record which has star it has id

Comment: _"I want to go to last row of current datasheet if I make a new record so it doesn't have the ID of current selection of table"_ -- The code above will do that if placed in a command button click event.
_"but if go to current new record which has star it has id"_ -- I am not following you here. Could you explain further?